# Как заблокировать определённый input при выборе одного из пункта select'a?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Доброго времени суток, как можно блокировать определённый input после выбора определённого пункта из меню select
имеется вот такой select

```
<select name="test" id="test">
<option value="dlina">Длина</option>
<option value="shirina">Ширина</option>
<option value="tolchina">Толщина</option>
</select>
```

И имеется вот такие input'ы

```
Укажите толщину (мм): <input type="text" name="h" id="h" value="0"  />
Укажите кол-во отверстий: <input type="text" id="hole" value="0">
Укажите длину реза (мм): <input type="text" id="cut" value="0">
```

Допустим если в select я выбираю Толщину то мне нужно чтобы поле hole(кол-во отверстий) стало неактивно для ввода

Comment: в вашем прошлом ответе фигурировал тэг `jquery`, в этом он не нужен случаем?

Comment: Можно и с jquery, разницы я особой не вижу если честно, мало еще опыта чтобы понимать что да как(

Comment: разница в том, что вам либо напишут ответ на jquery, либо будете ждать ответа на чистом js.

Comment: Понял спасибо, буду иметь ввиду)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тем или иным способом вам необходимо сопоставить пункты селекта и те инпуты, которые нужно отключать. В примере ниже сопоставление на основе дата атрибута, где перечислены идентификаторы отключаемых инпутов.

В принципе при таком подходе, в дата-атрибуте указвыается jquery-селектор, что дает возможность отключать инпуты не только по индентификатору, но и по классу, и по атрибутам, т.е. используя все те же селекторы.

```js
$("#test").change(function(){
   var disable = $(this).children("option:selected").data('disable');
   
   $("input").prop('disabled', false);
   
   if(disable != undefined){
      $(disable).val(null).prop('disabled', true);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="test" id="test">
  <option value="dlina">Длина</option>
  <option value="shirina">Ширина</option>
  <option value="tolchina" data-disable="#hole,#cut">Толщина</option>
</select>


<div>
  Укажите толщину (мм): <input type="text" name="h" id="h" value="0"  /><br>
  Укажите кол-во отверстий: <input type="text" id="hole" value="0"><br>
  Укажите длину реза (мм): <input type="text" id="cut" value="0"><br>
</div>
```

Comment: поставил минус - напиши в чем претензия (:

Comment: у Вас какой-то фарш в коде - зачем переменную вводить? зачем блокировать ВСЕ инпуты? зачем переменную на undefined проверять? откуда там вообще undefined возьмётся? :))

Comment: Спасибо данный способ работает, осталось только с css определиться чтобы поле какой нить закрашенное было

Comment: @humster_spb все инпуты не блокируются, а разблокируются. Вы же хотите, чтобы при смене на другой пункт прежние блокировки снялись? проверять на undefined надо, поскольку именно такое значение она будет иметь при отсутствии data-атрибута.